# Magento2 getting - Error filtering template error after add custom attribute value programmatically

Tags: magento2, attributes, model, object-manager

Getting this error when reload page after adding value programmatically in a custom attribute. And when i delete that value which i added programmatically then its working fine.

```
Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in 
/home/tunxxx/public_html/xxxxxx.com/app/design/frontend/Etheme/yourstore/Nwdthemes_Revslider/templates/revslider.phtml on line 87
```

i am using below given code for addding attribute value programatically.

```
<?php
//  $attribute_model = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute');

    $objectManager1 = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $attribute_model = $objectManager1->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute');


    $attribute_code = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'ymmk_model');
    $attribute = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);
    $value[0] = array('rrrrrrrrrfrrr','');
    $result = array('value' => $value);
    $attribute->setData('option',$result);
    $attribute->save();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeOptionManagementInterface::add`

Keep in mind that Magento typically wants you to use [dependency injection](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html) to instantiate your objects.

You should be using a [InstallData](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/prepare/lifecycle.html#data-initialization) class to insert those options. You should inject into your composer the `ProductAttributeOptionManagementInterface` and `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory`. It's a bad idea to do this kind of a thing in a template file...

This is what the install should look like (Replace \Vendor\Module with your vendor name and the module name):

```
<?php
// Location: <module_root_directory>/Setup/InstallData.php
namespace \Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeOptionManagementInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory;

class InstallData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var OptionFactory|null
     */
    protected $optionFactory;

    /**
     * @var ProductAttributeOptionManagementInterface|null
     */
    protected $attributeOptionManagementInterface;

    /**
     * InstallData constructor.
     *
     * @param ProductAttributeOptionManagementInterface $attributeOptionManagementInterface
     * @param OptionFactory $optionFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductAttributeOptionManagementInterface $attributeOptionManagementInterface,
        OptionFactory $optionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->attributeOptionManagementInterface = $attributeOptionManagementInterface;
        $this->optionFactory = $optionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $attributeCode = 'ymmk_model';
        $sortOrder = 10;
        $optionLabel = 'rrrrrrrrrfrrr';

        $option = $this->optionFactory->create();
        $option->setLabel($optionLabel);
        $option->setSortOrder($sortOrder);
        $this->attributeOptionManagementInterface->add(
            $attributeCode,
            $option
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how i will call this function? in which file ?

Comment: i think i got it i have to run this command **php magento setup:upgrade** can i run it multiple times ? like i want to test few think. but confuse if it require to uninstall module everytime for re-run it